# Move all entries from one OU to another OU in Oracle Unified Directory server

Tags: oracle, ldap, ldap-query

I am using Oracle Unified Directory ldap server and i want to rename OU which is having more user entries in it.I just executed below script in my staging ldap server to change the name of OU and it got worked and all user entries moved to new OU.

```
dn: ou=OLD,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modrdn
newrdn: ou=NEW
deleteoldrdn: 1
```

but below oracle documentation tells, we cannot rename if RDN has any childeren. 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1273/adding-modifying-and-deleting-directory-data.html

please suggest is it safe to rename ou using modrdn.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to Oracle on OUD, no.

MANY LDAP server implementations have the same limitation.

The LDAP server implementation controls this activity. Some LDAP server implementations of course do support performing a modRDN on a container.

AFIK, Microsoft Active Directory does.

eDirectory I know does as long as the container is a partition.

You can of course, perhaps, not ideal, create a new container with the new name and then modRDN the user within the "old" container into the new container.

Comment: how to export all users from old container and then move to new container?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just looked at the wrong documentation (OUD 11.1.1 was released in 2012).

Starting from 11.1.2.x (released in 2014), OUD [documentation no more lists that limitation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E49437_01/admin.111220/e22648/managing_data.htm#solTO-CHANTE-AN-RDN).